# Bitwise within catch

Tags: java, try-catch, bit-manipulation

I'm learning Java,and I found a paragraph of interesting coding on the internet, I forgot where I got them, but it is the code below, and it worked perfectly for compile and run, and anyone please introduce and explain this kind of bitwise opeartion to me.

```
String result = "";
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
//odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

try 
{
    result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
}
catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex)//I don't get how this work!.!
{
    System.out.println(ex);    
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So catch can handle 2 exceptions and this is introduced in java 7